# How to find the beginning and ending indices of groups of ones in a set of ones and zeros

Tags: c++

How would I find the beginning and ending indices of the groups of ones. I've tried some convoluted attempts with nested if statements and have had no success. Is there an algorithm that deals with this type of problem or does it have a name. Thanks.

```
int arr[32] = {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
             1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
             1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,
             0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
```

Comment: maybe `std::find` ?

Comment: Lookup RLL encoding for ideas

Comment: Well, the first group begins at the first one, and ends just before the next 0. The next group begins at the next 1 and ends just before the next 0. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: to get help you would need to show your attempt. Actually I cant imagine how convoluted it can get, you basically have to iterate throught the array and find elements for which `arr[i] != arr[i+1]` and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this algorithm has specific name, but here is variant to consider:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 32) {
    while (i < 32 && arr[i] == 0) i++;
    if (i < 32) {
        cout << "Found start index " << i << endl;
        while (i < 32 && arr[i] == 1) i++;
        cout << "Found end index " << (i - 1) << endl;
    }
}

// of course move 32 to local variable outside the loop
```

the main idea: skip all 0s, if we haven't reached end of array - find all 1s, repeat